# Leaflet, get z-index of certain layer

Tags: leaflet

I'm currently working on a application where I want to save the current layer settings for every user. So I also want to save the order of the layers the user currently sees. I'm able to set the z-index like this:`layer.setZIndex(zIndex)` .

But how can I get the z-index of the layers when the user is adding and removing layers? There is no function like `layer.getZIndex()` available in leaflet.

Comment: Are you talking about Base layers (Title Layer) or Overlay layers? Could you be more specific and also provide some sample codes here?

Comment: I'm talking about TileLayers, the background layers of the map. I just want to get to know the order of these TileLayers on the map. Also I'm gonna look for some useful code to add here.

Comment: Base layers are mutually exclusive (only one can be visible on your map at a time). So z-index doesn't actually mean anything in that case.

Comment: My bad for not being clear enough. In my case they're not mutually exclusive because the user can change the opacity of the tilelayers. So there maybe multiple background layers visible at the same time.

Comment: A sample code could go a long way here.